# Elsarticle - Bibliography

Tags: elsarticle

I am trying to complile an elsarticle tex document.

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

I want to refer to an article which hasn't an year. In the sample.bib, I wrote

```
@article{JG,
author    = "J. Gindele and W. Novak and P. Fietkau and P. Neuwirth and W. Leitermann",
title     = "The Transaxle Powertrain of the Mercedes-AMG Sports Cars",
}
```

The problem is in the section of the refernce where I have those interogation points related with the article year

[image]

I used also

```
@misc{JG,
author    = "J. Gindele and W. Novak and P. Fietkau and P. Neuwirth and W. Leitermann",
title     = "The Transaxle Powertrain of the Mercedes-AMG Sports Cars",
}
```

But I have the same problem. How Can I remove this interrogation point from the year place

Comment: How can an article not have a `year`? If you want to change that, you'll have to change it in the `.bst`, unless you use some other reference manager (like [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)).

Comment: Since the piece wasn't published in a journal, it would be wrong to use the `@article` entry type. Using the type `@misc` seems far more appropriate. From a quick perusal of the paper, it was circulated last year. Thus, set the field `year=2015` and BibTeX and LaTeX will be happy.